# how to use dynamic where condition in eloquent laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My working code is

```
$query = DB::table('order');

    $fromorderdate = $request->get('fromorderdate') or "";
    $toorderdate = $request->get('toorderdate') or "";
    $fromdeliverydate = $request->get('fromdeliverydate') or "";
    $todeliverydate = $request->get('todeliverydate') or "";
    $orderstatus = $request->get('orderstatus') or "";
    $ordertype = $request->get('ordertype') or "";

    if (Input::get('weightrange')) {
        $weightrangearray = explode('.', Input::get('weightrange'));
        $weightrange1 = $weightrangearray[0];
        $weightrange2 = $weightrangearray[1];
    }

    if ($fromorderdate != "" && $toorderdate != "") {

        $query->whereBetween('orderdate', [$fromorderdate, $toorderdate]);
        $makequery = true;

    }
    if ($fromdeliverydate && $todeliverydate) {
        $query->whereBetween('orderdate', [$fromdeliverydate, $todeliverydate]);
        $makequery = true;

    }

    if ($fromdeliverydate && $todeliverydate) {
        $query->whereBetween('orderdate', [$weightrange1, $weightrange2]);
        $makequery = true;

    }
    if ($orderstatus) {
        $query->where('orderstatus', $orderstatus);
        $makequery = true;

    }
    if ($ordertype) {
        $query->where('ordertype', $ordertype);
        $makequery = true;

    }


        echo $query->toSql();
    if ($makequery) {
        $order = $query->get();
    }
```

This code is working fine but the exact problem is that i cant use eloquent relations on this `$order` variable.

What i tried `$query=new Order();// order is my model name`
but sql query is not working properly.

is there any way so that i can convert this `$order`db instance to eloquent so that i can use my relations in view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`when($condition, callback)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses):

```
$orders = Order::when($request->has('fromorderdate') && $request->has('toorderdate'), function ($q) use ($request) {
    return $q->whereBetween('orderdate', [$request->fromorderdate, $request->toorderdate]);
})
->when...
->get();
```